# Dimension of orbit versus invariant functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, birational-geometry, invariant-theory

$\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}$Let $K = \CC(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and let $G$ be a countable group of automorphisms of $K$; in the cases I care about, $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Then the field of $G$-invariants, $K^G$, is an extension of $\CC$ of some transendence degree $d$. I would like to know under what circumstances I can say that the Zariski closure of the $G$-orbit of a generic $n$-tuple has dimension $n-d$.

I want to be a little sloppy about what I mean by generic, but I don't think there is anything deep in that issue. For "generic" $x  \in \CC^n$, all the rational maps $g$ are defined at $x$, so we can consider $\{ g(x) \}_{g \in G} \subset \CC^n$ and take its Zariski closure. Every function in $K^G$ is constant on this Zariski closure, so the Zariski closure has dimension $\leq n-d$.

**Question** Can I conclude that the dimension is "generically" $n-d$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes for $G=\mathbb Z$, see Theorem 4.1 of this paper by [Amerik-Campana](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510299.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! Following up on your answer, I have found a paper which does the general case; see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Following citation links from the paper Jorge directed me to, the case of general $G$ is done in

*Bell, Jason; Ghioca, Dragos; Reichstein, Zinovy*, [**On a dynamical version of a theorem of Rosenlicht**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2422/2036-2145.201501_005), Ann. Sc. Norm. Super. Pisa, Cl. Sci. (5) 17, No. 1, 187-204 (2017). [ZBL1401.14071](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1401.14071). ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.4744))

Disclaimer -- I have only read the MR review.